# With Rails 4 and structured logging, how can I add the request id field to logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, logstash

I am adding structured logging to a Rails 4 app. Using [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) and [logstash-logger](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger) as describe in [this article](https://kartar.net/2015/12/structured-logging/), I've got things mostly working.

I'm having trouble adding request id to the logs. The closest I've found is to add this to `config/${ENV}.rb`:

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid]
```

But this adds the request id to the tags list, instead of adding it as a named field.

```
{
  "tags": [
    "da76b4be-01ae-4cc4-8d3c-87062ea02cfe"
  ],
  "host": "services",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2016-09-13T17:24:34.883+00:00",
  "message": "..."
}
```

This is problematic. It makes it more awkward and less obvious on how to search for a particular request id. Plus, parsing the message in logstash it overwrites any other tags that are already associated with the log message.

Is there any way that I can add the request id to the log as a named field?

```
{
  "request_id", "da76b4be-01ae-4cc4-8d3c-87062ea02cfe",
  "host": "services",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2016-09-13T17:24:34.883+00:00",
  "message": "..."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but maybe it will help someone like me who struggled to find a simple way to do this.

Using the `custom_payload` (instead of `custom_options`), you can directly access the request received by the controller and get its id to add it to the logs:

```rb
config.lograge.custom_payload do |controller|
  {
    request_id: controller.request.request_id
  }
end
```

No need to configure the `log_tags` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. From Lograge, you can use the `custom_options`:

```
  # all your lograge stuff...
  config.lograge.enabled = true

  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    # use the `event.payload`
    {uuid: event.payload[:uuid]}
  end
```

You can overload any option in here - they'll take over the lib's ones.

The code responsible for this is [here](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/blob/0cb40f017c67f19ca6aade1981cfd3273fcf286f/lib/lograge/log_subscriber.rb#L40). The test that shows it work is [here](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/blob/c0f4315d71b6f2b3a2dab298e2fb80202569fbb4/spec/lograge_logsubscriber_spec.rb#L48-L53).

Comment: I tried this, but the `payload` hash has no uuid field. I only get `"uuid": null` in my logs.

Comment: I found that you need `append_info_to_payload` defined in the `ApplicationController` for this to work (see https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/blob/master/README.md). But this only adds the custom fields to the access logs. For the UUID to be useful, it needs to be in all the logs associated with that request (in the same way that Rails puts the tags on every log entry).